# Как на jQuery получить значение margin с десятичными знаками?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Простейший код:

```js
var marginleft = jQuery(this).find(".image").css("margin-left");
var paddingleft = jQuery(this).find(".image").css("padding-left");
```

Результат выдается с целыми числами.
Проблема в том, что если margin задан через em, то Chrome высчитывает его с десятичными значениями, а Firefox значения округляет. В итоге я не могу точно позиционировать элемент в хроме, там вечно на 1px перебор, так как подсчитанный margin-left у него скажем 23.9998, а jQuery дает только 23.

Comment: а почему не взять чистым js? Он же не округляет

Comment: он вроде как может выдать результат в em, а мне нужны px значения.

Comment: нет, он возвращает `px`, даже если указан `em`. Т.к. это рассчитанные поля с помощью `getComputedStyle(node)`